# Remainder when $^{40}C_{12}$ is divided by $7$.

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, binomial-theorem

I was solving a binomial summation problem, and I got $^{40}C_{12}$ as the answer. Now, the question demands to find the remainder when it is divided by $7$. $40!$ can be divided $5$ times by $7$ (using a famous GIF trick.) Unfortunately, $28!$ and $12!$ can be divided $4$ and $1$ time respectively by $7$, and hence the answer is clearly not zero. I am hence unable to find a way to deduce the remainder (without using a calculator to calculate $^{40}C_{12}$).

Comment: The possibility exists that 40C12 is the wrong answer, but since you haven't included your original problem, we can't help you decide whether that's the case.

Comment: It can be done by hand. Keep in mind that $x+7 \equiv x \mod 7$ and using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem should make it quite fast to find an answer

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem

Answer (score 7):

We could do the binomial expansion of $(x+1)^{40}$ in the seven-element field, by exploiting that $(x+1)^7=x^7+1$, so
$$
(x+1)^{40}=((x+1)^7)^5(x+1)^5=(x^7+1)^5(x+1)^5
$$
The power $x^{12}$ can only be obtained as $x^7$ from the first factor, where the coefficient is $\binom{5}{1}=5$ and $x^5$ from the second, where the coefficient is $1$. Therefore
$$
\binom{40}{12}\equiv5\pmod{7}
$$

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
\binom{40}{12}
&=
\frac
{(40)\cdots (29)}
{(12)\cdots (1)}
\\[6pt]
&=
\Bigl(\frac{40}{12}{\cdots}\frac{36}{8}\Bigr)
{\,\cdot\,}
5
{\,\cdot\,}
\Bigl(\frac{34}{6}{\cdots}\frac{29}{1}\Bigr)
\\[6pt]
&\equiv
\bigl(1{\cdots}1\bigr)
{\,\cdot\,}
5
{\,\cdot\,}
\bigl(1{\cdots}1\bigr)
\;(\text{mod}\;7)&&\text{[since each fraction in the above line}
\\[0pt] 
&&&\;\text{reduces to $1$, mod $7$]}
\\[4pt]
&\equiv
5
\;(\text{mod}\;7)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}